# How to set Time zone permanently in Amazon Workspace?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-workspaces

I have an amazon workspace windows instance (Server 2016).

I want to set the time zone to Eastern Standard Time. I want that the time zone must remain unchanged after restarting the workspace or logging into the workspace via AWS client.

For this reason, I have seen the documentation of the AWS workspace and disabled the time zone redirection by using the group policy management tool. I have seen the documentation from the given link.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/workspaces/latest/adminguide/group_policy.html#gp_time_zone

Now, the time zone of the workspace is fixed to Central Time (US and Canada). I can change it to Eastern Standard Time but the change does not permanent. When I log in to this workspace or restart it go back to Central Time (US and Canada).

Thanks in advance.

[edited]
The screenshot of the setting are given below-

[Overridable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vByvx.png)
[Non-overridable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y7pFM.png)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you follow all the steps provided in the documentation.

To allow the user to override your setting, choose Overridable Administrator Defaults; otherwise, choose Not Overridable Administrator Defaults.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/workspaces/latest/adminguide/group_policy.html#gp_time_zone

Comment: Thank you for your response. 
Now, the time-zone redirection is disabled. Because my time zone is Bangladesh Standard Time but when I log in to the workspace the time zone is fixed to Central Time (US and Canada). Now the problem is when I change it to Eastern Standard Time it does not persist. After login or restart the workspace it changed to  Central Time (US and Canada).

Comment: Make sure you follow all steps that are mentioned in the documentation. Could you provide me with screenshots of your settings and configuration?

Comment: I have added the screenshot in the post. Thank you.

Comment: If you want to allow the user to override your setting, choose Overridable Administrator Defaults; If you do not want to let the user override choose Not Overridable Administrator Defaults. -----You should ONLY set the disabled in the overridable administrator defaults. NOT in the not overridable administrator defaults.

Comment: I do accordingly but the result is the same as before.

Comment: After updating the group policy, did you: 1. reboot the workspace 2. Run gpupdate /force 3. Change the timezone 4. Check if it persist

Comment: Yes, done them. But same as before not working.

Comment: @Ashraful - Did you ever get to the bottom of this? I'm having the exact same problem. I have setup the override and can change the timezone when logging in, however the changed timezone isn't persisting and it's reverting to UTC on 2 of our Workspaces, but 2 others are set to CST!

Answer (score 0):

The AWS Workspace is a plugin and play so you need to set the local time in your physical machine i,e outside the workspace as you want in the workspace and restart both aws and local machine.

Comment: Sorry but this is just plain wrong. Read the AWS workspace docs - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/workspaces/latest/adminguide/group_policy.html#gp_time_zone