# AWS Timezone Redirection

Tags: amazon-web-services

I've been trying to find a way to disable the AWS workspace to change time zone after every reboot. E.g. I configure the time zone in the workspace to be Central Time; but on reboot, the machine sets itself back to Eastern.

I have tried disabling Time Zone Redirection, but no dice.

Any help?

Comment: Perhaps: [How to set Time zone permanently in Amazon Workspace? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69059411/how-to-set-time-zone-permanently-in-amazon-workspace)

Comment: I've tried what they did and the person that posted the question could not get it working as well